# laravel 10 "Token mismatch" on using web-routes

Tags: laravel-sanctum, mismatch, laravel-10, x-xsrf-token

I am new to Laravel and Angular. I am using Angular as frontend on localhost:4200 and Laravel only as backend-system on localhost:8000. For authentication I use Sanctum. On my attempt to login firstly I request the XSRF-Token which is successfully set as Cookie and also sent in the header to request the login.
At the beginning I had my login route in `api.php` because I am using a seperate frontend. But there I got the Error "Session store not set on request". For this Problem I red that it is necessary to use the web.php when you use XSRF-Token. But is this right? Even in the documentation they use "api" so I am not sure which route file to use.
After that I switched my login route to `web.php` and got now the Error "Token mismatch". Since days I am stuck on this problem and I don't find a way to solve this.

What I tried:

- put the routes under the web-group in the web.php
- In `sanctum.php` I set all possible URLs I use as `stateful`